# How the chemical reaction is happening?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I have got this [IMAGE](https://media.giphy.com/media/C5M0uy5DThIxa/giphy.gif) peculiar chemical reaction and  tried to find reason behind it. But I couldn't. Can you write the reason?

Comment: It's hydrophobic sand, I think. Apparently called 'Magic Sand' : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_sand.

Comment: It isn't really a "chemical reaction" since there isn't a product made from reactants.